# Иконка уходит за кнопку (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Иконка уходит за кнопку , смотрите скриншот.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<i class="fas fa-calendar-alt" style="margin-left:-120px;font-size:22px;color:#059bce"></i>
```

Comment: Я вставляю код с помощью Font Awesome 5

Comment: какой тег используете ?

Comment: тэг <i> , код выше.

Comment: а сам font-awesome подключили ?

Comment: Да, как видите иконка то отображается

Comment: вы весь код покажите - не ясно что и откуда уплывает - для вставки font-awesome в сниппет stackoverflow воспользуйтесь font-awesome cdn от bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я тебя правильно понял то это должно выглядеть так. тег `i` нужно вставлять внутрь обьекта в котором ты хочешь его видеть. А после ты можешь дать родителю `position: relative`, а самой иконке `position: absolute` и пихать ее куда захочешь и никуда она не спрячется.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button>asdasd <i class='fa fa-bars'></i> asdasd</button>
```

Comment: я же спросил font-awesome подключен или нет